# Iterating through ICollection to return a bool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am essentially creating a blog (with slightly different naming conventions). I have a property on my "post" class (which I call a story) that is tied to a table called "visibility". A post can either be public or private.

When a user views another member's profile, they should be able to see all the public posts.

I've created a viewmodel:

```
public class UserDetailsViewModel
{
    public bool IsRegisteredUser { get; set; }
    //public bool IsStoryPrivate { get; set; }
    public int StoryCount { get; set; }
    public int ReviewCount { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Story> Stories { get; set; }
}
```

In my users controller, when someone clicks on the profile to view the details of the profile, I get the user from the database, get all the stories (posts) associated with that user and include the various tables tied to the post, get the number of posts, and plug those values into my view model. That is done with this code:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    //verify an id was passed 
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    //if an id was given as a parameter, find the user associated with that id
    var foundUser = dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    //verify a user was found
    if (foundUser == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var isRegisteredUser = IsRegisteredUser(foundUser);

    //if a user was found, get all stories associated with the foundUser
    var stories = dbContext.Stories
        .Include("Genre")
        .Include("StoryType")
        .Include("StoryAgeRange")
        .Include("Visibility")
        .Where(x => x.AuthorId == foundUser.Id);

    var reviews = dbContext.Reviews.Where(x => x.ReviewerId == foundUser.Id);

    int numOfStories = stories.Count();
    int numOfReviews = reviews.Count();

    //create the viewmodel
    var viewModel = new UserDetailsViewModel
    {
        User = foundUser,
        //IsStoryPrivate = isStoryPrivate,
        IsRegisteredUser = isRegisteredUser,
        Stories = stories,
        StoryCount = numOfStories,
        ReviewCount = numOfReviews
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

What I want to do is create a method called IsStoryPrivate that returns a boolean and needs to iterate through each story in the stories. Then pass the true/false value to the viewModel in the IsStoryPrivate field.

I've tried with this code:

```
public bool IsStoryPrivate(Story story)
{
    return story.Visibility.Name == "Private";
}
```

then tried to call it in the controller but that failed because I'm not passing a single story object into the method but a collection - or list of stories.

Then I tried this:

```
public bool IsStoryPrivate(ICollection<Story> story)
{
    foreach (story in story)
    {
        return Story.Visibility.Name == "Private";
    }
}
```

Which also lead to errors. I'm not sure how to write the code to iterate over the list of stories returned from the db and give me a true/false for each one which I can send to the viewmodel.

Comment: You may want to clarify what exactly it is you are trying to determine with the boolean: all stories public, at least one public, .. ?

Comment: You can filter for private stories if you want: `var privateStories = stories.Where(story => story.Visibility.Name == "Private");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than getting all stories from the database and then deciding whether to show them or not, do the filter on the initial query:

```
var stories = dbContext.Stories
    .Include("Genre")
    .Include("StoryType")
    .Include("StoryAgeRange")
    .Include("Visibility")
    .Where(x => x.AuthorId == foundUser.Id);

// filter for public stories only when the author is not the current user
if (!isRegisteredUser)
{
    stories = stories.Where(x => x.Visibility.Name == "Public");
}
```

If you were loading the `Visibilty` relation for the check, you can omit it now:

```
var stories = dbContext.Stories
    .Include("Genre")
    .Include("StoryType")
    .Include("StoryAgeRange")
    .Where(x => x.AuthorId == foundUser.Id);
```

Comment: I actually don't want to do that because I need an if/else in my razor view. So if the logged in user is the same person as the profile they're viewing (meaning they're looking at their own profile) they should be able to see all their posts - public and private. But if a user is not looking at their own profile but rather someone else's, they should only see that person's public posts. Which is why I have IsRegisteredUser bool in there that checks the ids of the logged in user to the user profile being viewed.

Comment: @J.G.Sable You don't need to dump that kind of work to the view, that corresponds to the controller. See my update

Comment: Good solution! Thank you.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You probably don't need to Include the visibility anymore, since you know they're public

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that understand you correct.
If you need to set single bool value (like "if any story is private, then set  it to true")

```
 var viewModel = new UserDetailsViewModel
{
    User = foundUser,
    IsStoryPrivate = stories.Any(x => IsStoryPrivate(x)), // or simply .Any(IsStoryPrivate)
    IsRegisteredUser = isRegisteredUser,
    Stories = stories,
    StoryCount = numOfStories,
    ReviewCount = numOfReviews
};
```

or you can use `All` instead of `Any`, if you need to set up it if all stories are private